# Parsing error from ms excel to java object , java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "447475.0"

Tags: java

I am reading microsoft excel data as string value [image]

Actually, I am reading value in java as string java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "447475.0"

Code snippet
Long.parseLong(getCellValue(row.getCell(positionMap.get(columnName))))

Comment: Please provide a https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This value with `.` is `double`. You should parse `double` from the stirng and then convert it to `long`.

```java
String str = "447475.0";
long num = (long) Double.parseDouble(str);  // 447475
```